# Explain Strange Synchronization in WCF Source Code

Tags: c#, wcf, synchronization, try-catch

While looking at the source code of System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferManager, I noticed this method:

```
void TuneQuotas()
{
    if (areQuotasBeingTuned)
        return;

    bool lockHeld = false;
    try
    {
        try { }
        finally
        {
            lockHeld = Monitor.TryEnter(tuningLock);
        }

        // Don't bother if another thread already has the lock
        if (!lockHeld || areQuotasBeingTuned)
            return;
        areQuotasBeingTuned = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockHeld)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(tuningLock);
        }
    }
    //
    // DO WORK... (code removed for brevity)
    //
    areQuotasBeingTuned = false;
}
```

Obviously, they want only one thread to run `TuneQuotas()`, and other threads to not wait if it is already being run by another thread. I should note that the code removed was not try protected.

I'm trying to understand the advantages of this method above *over just doing this*:

```
void TuneQuotas()
{
    if(!Monitor.TryEnter(tuningLock)) return;
    //
    // DO WORK...
    //
    Monitor.Exit(tuningLock);
}
```

Any ideas why they might have bothered with all that?  I suspect the way they use the `finally` blocks is to guard against a thread abort scenario, but I still don't see the point because, even with all this code, `TuneQuotas()` would be *locked for good* if that one thread doesn't make it all the way to the end to set `areQuotasBeingTunes=false`,  for one reason or another. So is there something cool about this pattern that I'm missing?

**EDIT:**
As a side note, it seems the method exists in .NET 4.0, which I confirmed using this code running on framework 4 (although I cannot confirm that the content of the method hasn't changed from what I found on the web):

```
var buffMgr = BufferManager.CreateBufferManager(1, 1);
var pooledBuffMgrType = buffMgr.GetType()
    .GetProperty("InternalBufferManager")
    .GetValue(buffMgr, null)
    .GetType();

Debug.WriteLine(pooledBuffMgrType.Module.FullyQualifiedName);
foreach (var methodInfo in pooledBuffMgrType
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(methodInfo.Name);
}
```

which outputs:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__3    1bf3856ad364e35\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll
ChangeQuota
DecreaseQuota
FindMostExcessivePool
FindMostStarvedPool
FindPool
IncreaseQuota
TuneQuotas
Finalize
MemberwiseClone
```

Comment: Certainly looks like a worthy submission to The Daily WTF...

Comment: Where are you getting this "source code"?  If you're looking at it through reflection with a tool like Reflector, ILSpy or JustDecompile, keep in mind that what it shows you is a representation of optimized IL, it may not have been written the way it shows.  It may not have been written in C# event...

Comment: @PeterRitchie I found it at this [link](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/WCF/WCF/3@5@30729@1/untmp/Orcas/SP/ndp/cdf/src/WCF/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/BufferManager@cs/1/BufferManager@cs), which probably points at the src published by MS. Downloading .net 4.5 src as we speak. Though I'm not so concerned about the src being accurate as much as trying to understand it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add some comments:

```
void TuneQuotas()
{
    if (areQuotasBeingTuned)
        return; //fast-path, does not require locking

    bool lockHeld = false;
    try
    {
        try { }
        finally
        {
            //finally-blocks cannot be aborted by Thread.Abort
            //The thread could be aborted after getting the lock and before setting lockHeld
            lockHeld = Monitor.TryEnter(tuningLock);
        }

        // Don't bother if another thread already has the lock
        if (!lockHeld || areQuotasBeingTuned)
            return; //areQuotasBeingTuned could have switched to true in the mean-time
        areQuotasBeingTuned = true; //prevent others from needlessly trying to lock (trigger fast-path)
    }
    finally //ensure the lock being released
    {
        if (lockHeld)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(tuningLock);
        }
    }
    //
    // DO WORK... (code removed for brevity)
    //
    //this might be a bug. There should be a call to Thread.MemoryBarrier,
    //or areQuotasBeingTuned should be volatile
    //if not, the write might never reach other processor cores
    //maybe this doesn't matter for x86
    areQuotasBeingTuned = false;
}
```

The simple version you gave does not protect against some problems. At the very least it is not exception-safe (lock won't be released). Interestingly, the "sophisticated" version, doesn't either.

This method has been removed from .NET 4.

Comment: True! That is indeed a severe bug. Maybe for that reason the method was removed in .NET 4.

Comment: Uh, that pretty much answers the question. How could you tell it was removed? Downloaded the source code?

Comment: Reflector shows 3.0 and 4.0 versions in its assembly list. Google also only finds that method in 3.5

Comment: Looks like the method still exists in .Net 4. See the update.

Comment: Interestingly, it has moved to the DurableInstancing which I didn't look at. The code is different, but the flaw that you discovered is still present.

Answer (score 1):

Until .NET 4.0 there was essentially a bug in the code that was generated by a `lock` statment.  It would generate something similar to the following:

```
Monitor.Enter(lockObject)
// see next paragraph
try
{
    // code that was in the lock block
}
finally
{
   Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
}
```

This means that if an exception occurred between `Enter` and `try`, the `Exit` would never be called.  As usr alluded to, this could happen due to `Thread.Abort`.

Your example:

```
if(!Monitor.TryEnter(tuningLock)) return;
//
// DO WORK...
//
Monitor.Exit(tuningLock);
```

Suffers from this problem and more.  The window in which this code and become interrupted and `Exit` not be called is basically the whole block of code--by any exception (not just one from `Thread.Abort`).

I have no idea *why* most code was written in .NET.  But, I surmise that this code was written to avoid the problem of an exception between `Enter` and `try`.  Let's look at some of the details:

```
try{}
finally
{
  lockHeld = Monitor.TryEnter(tuningLock);
}
```

`Finally` blocks basically generate a constrained execution region in IL.  Constrained execution regions cannot be interrupted by anything.  So, putting the `TryEnter` in the `finally` block above ensures that `lockHeld` reliably holds the state of the `lock`.

That block of code is contained in a `try`/`finally` block whose `finally` statement calls `Monitor.Exit` if `tuningLock` is true.  This means that there is no point between the `Enter` and the `try` block that can be interrupted.

FWIW, this method was still in .NET 3.5 and is visible in the WCF 3.5 source code (not the .NET source code).  I don't know yet what's in 4.0; but I would imagine it would be the same; there's no reason to change working code even if the impetus for part of its structure no longer exists.

For more details on what `lock` *used* to generate see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/08/17/subtleties-of-c-il-codegen.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. As mentioned in the Q, I suspected finally's were for a thread abort, but the part I found confusing was that it doesn't provide full protection from thread abort (or exceptions) since `areQuotasBeingTunes=false` is not in a finally. do you think this could be fixed by moving the (DO WORK) part inside the try-block right after `are...=true`, and `are...=false` inside the last finally-block right after `Monitor.Exit`?

Comment: Well, I don't know the entire logic around `BufferManager` and `TuneQuota`; but it does seem like there is a race condition there.  It's *seems* that `Thread.Abort` could come in and make it so that `areQuotasBeingTuned` will remain true for the life of that `PooledBufferManager` instance.  But, I don't know if a `Thread.Abort `would also mean the instance would get recycled...  I'd have to look at the code in more depth.

Comment: I don't even know how likely it is that someone can even get the thread that `TuneQuota` is running on to call `Thread.Abort`.  In all likelihood, there was internal communication within Microsoft about the problem with `lock` and code reviews focused solely on that and resulted in the code you posted being created--regardless of the likelihood or possibility of whether `lock` was ever possibly a problem.

Comment: It looks like `TuneQuota` is being called from inside the public `TakeBuffer` method. So it is perfectly possible a client calls `TakeBuffer` and aborts the calling thread.

Comment: If it were me, the `areQuotasBeginTuned = false` wouldn't be dangling there; but, I didn't write the code.  You could log it on Microsoft Connect; but, to get much traction would require example code the shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas why they might have bothered with all that?

After running some tests, I think see one reason (if not THE reason): They probably bothered with all that because it is MUCH faster!

It turns out `Monitor.TryEnter` is an **expensive** call IF the object is *already locked* (if it's not locked, `TryEnter` is still very fast -- no problems there). So all threads, except the first one, are going to experience the slowness.

I didn't think this would matter that much; since afterall, each thread is going to try taking the lock just once and then move on (not like they'd be sitting there, trying in a loop). However, I wrote some code for comparison and it showed that the cost of `TryEnter` (when already locked) is significant. In fact, on my system each call took about 0.3 ms without the debugger attached, which is several orders of magnitude slower than using a simple boolean check.

So I suspect, this probably showed up in Microsoft's test results, so they optimized the code as above, by adding the fast track boolean check. But that's just my guess..